# node js promise, err message is not handle

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a function that return a promise reject with a new error when it's necessary. I wrote a message but this message can't be handle by the .then of the promise. It's set as undefined .
Here the function :

```
exports.addBrand = function (user, data) {
    /** Mandatory data **/
    let name = "'" + data.brand.name + "'"
    let idAdvertiser = data.brand.idAdvertiser
    /** Optional data **/
    let isDefaultBillingEntity = data.brand.isDefaultBillingEntity === undefined ? null : data.brand.isDefaultBillingEntity
    if (name === undefined || idAdvertiser === undefined) return Promise.reject(new Error('A Brand name and an advertiser id should be provide'))
    return tools.execSQLQuery(query)
    .then(result => result[0])
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

And i call this function by this way in an other file :

```
var addBrand = (req, res) => {
  Brand.addBrand(req.user, req.body)
    .then(result => res.status(201).json({success: true, ui_info: 'Brand created.', ui_type: 'good', data: {brand: result}}))
    .catch(err => res.status(403).json({success: false, message: err}))
}
```

The problem is that the message: err show "message: {}" in my json response.
When it succeed there is no problem i have my data send. Why the return Promise.reject does work but not the message in the error ?

Thank for reading

Comment: The `.catch` in your first snippet should rethrow the error, not log just it. Something like this: `.catch(err => {console.log(err); throw err; })`.

Comment: Yeah i ll handle that soon. But actually this line : 
return Promise.reject(new Error('A Brand name and an advertiser id should be provide'))
end the function so the catch is never reach, as i wish. But the sentence ' a brand name .... ' is show as undefined in my second snippet. Why ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to to use `err.message`, like this: `{success: false, message: err.message}`. All `Error` objects have a `message` property and that's the string you're looking for.

Longer answer (you can look up elsewhere) is that the `Error` object doesn't "stringify" all that well. For a standard `JSON.stringify()`, you'd need something like this: `JSON.stringify(err, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)` I would not suggest that in your case because you do not want to expose your stack traces in client facing error responses!